# R - Appending number to string leaves space before single digits

Tags: r

I wrote a function to add an identifier to each character in a vector. (_Instance1, etc.) However, when I run my code, I get a space in front of my single digit ID's. Is there a way to remove the space? For example, for a vector of characters ("Hi", "Hello") I get ("Hi_Instance 1", "Hello_Instance 1"). Once I get past 10 it's fine. Here is my code:

```
convert <- function(x) {
df <- as.data.frame(x)
df <- df %>% mutate(dummy = row_number())
df <- df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% ungroup()
x = apply(df, 1, function(row) {paste(row['x'], '_Instance', row['id'], sep = '')})
df['id']= NULL

return(x)
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you're not just using `paste`, e.g. `paste0(c("Hi", "Hello"), "_Instance1")` ?

Comment: Use `paste0` instead of `paste`. It has no separator and collapses vectors into a single string automatically

Comment: I just tried paste0 but there is still a space in font of the single digit instances

Comment: 1) `return x` is not valid R code, you need `(` and `)`. 2) You could at least end the function. (With `}`.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly explain why this is happening ... but here's an alternative that works:

```
convert <- function(x) {
  df <- data_frame(x = as.character(x$x)) %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup()
  paste(df[['x']], "_Instance", df[['id']], sep = "")
}

head(mutate(mtcars, x=cyl))
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb x
# 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 6
# 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 6
# 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 4
# 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 6
# 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 8
# 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 6

convert(mutate(mtcars, x=cyl))
#  [1] "6_Instance1"  "6_Instance2"  "4_Instance1"  "6_Instance3"  "8_Instance1"  "6_Instance4" 
#  [7] "8_Instance2"  "4_Instance2"  "4_Instance3"  "6_Instance5"  "6_Instance6"  "8_Instance3" 
# [13] "8_Instance4"  "8_Instance5"  "8_Instance6"  "8_Instance7"  "8_Instance8"  "4_Instance4" 
# [19] "4_Instance5"  "4_Instance6"  "4_Instance7"  "8_Instance9"  "8_Instance10" "8_Instance11"
# [25] "8_Instance12" "4_Instance8"  "4_Instance9"  "4_Instance10" "8_Instance13" "6_Instance7" 
# [31] "8_Instance14" "4_Instance11"
```

Enhancement: I like to keep artificial keys like this easily sortable, but if you try to sort them you'll see that the "id" component is not facilitating that:

```
sort(convert(mutate(mtcars, x=cyl)))
#  [1] "4_Instance1"  "4_Instance10" "4_Instance11" "4_Instance2"  "4_Instance3"  "4_Instance4" 
#  [7] "4_Instance5"  "4_Instance6"  "4_Instance7"  "4_Instance8"  "4_Instance9"  "6_Instance1" 
# [13] "6_Instance2"  "6_Instance3"  "6_Instance4"  "6_Instance5"  "6_Instance6"  "6_Instance7" 
# [19] "8_Instance1"  "8_Instance10" "8_Instance11" "8_Instance12" "8_Instance13" "8_Instance14"
# [25] "8_Instance2"  "8_Instance3"  "8_Instance4"  "8_Instance5"  "8_Instance6"  "8_Instance7" 
# [31] "8_Instance8"  "8_Instance9"
```

(Notice 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, ...)

Another alternative, where the largest integer within the group drives the number of leading zeroes:

```
convert <- function(x) {
  df <- data_frame(x = as.character(x$x)) %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(
      id = row_number(),
      id = sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(as.character(id))), "d"), id)
    )
  paste(df[['x']], "_Instance", df[['id']], sep = "")
}
sort(convert(mutate(mtcars, x=cyl)))
#  [1] "4_Instance01" "4_Instance02" "4_Instance03" "4_Instance04" "4_Instance05" "4_Instance06"
#  [7] "4_Instance07" "4_Instance08" "4_Instance09" "4_Instance10" "4_Instance11" "6_Instance1" 
# [13] "6_Instance2"  "6_Instance3"  "6_Instance4"  "6_Instance5"  "6_Instance6"  "6_Instance7" 
# [19] "8_Instance01" "8_Instance02" "8_Instance03" "8_Instance04" "8_Instance05" "8_Instance06"
# [25] "8_Instance07" "8_Instance08" "8_Instance09" "8_Instance10" "8_Instance11" "8_Instance12"
# [31] "8_Instance13" "8_Instance14"
```

or you can do it globally, not just per-group:

```
convert <- function(x) {
  df <- data_frame(x = as.character(x$x)) %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(id = sprintf(paste0("%0", max(nchar(as.character(id))), "d"), id))
  paste(df[['x']], "_Instance", df[['id']], sep = "")
}
sort(convert(mutate(mtcars, x=cyl)))
#  [1] "4_Instance01" "4_Instance02" "4_Instance03" "4_Instance04" "4_Instance05" "4_Instance06"
#  [7] "4_Instance07" "4_Instance08" "4_Instance09" "4_Instance10" "4_Instance11" "6_Instance01"
# [13] "6_Instance02" "6_Instance03" "6_Instance04" "6_Instance05" "6_Instance06" "6_Instance07"
# [19] "8_Instance01" "8_Instance02" "8_Instance03" "8_Instance04" "8_Instance05" "8_Instance06"
# [25] "8_Instance07" "8_Instance08" "8_Instance09" "8_Instance10" "8_Instance11" "8_Instance12"
# [31] "8_Instance13" "8_Instance14"
```

(They don't sort globally perfectly, but the numbering might be considered more consistent. It's partly aesthetic at this point.)

Some comments about code efficiency in your example:

- Since you do not return `df`, you do not need to remove the `"id"` field; realize that R is passing the frame *by value*, meaning that the calling environment never sees the changes to the frame
- Using `apply(..., 1, ...)` with a `data.frame` is doable but often problematic, especially if there are any `numeric` in the frame, as it converts everything. If you are working with large-ish data, this can be resource-consuming.
- Since you use `paste` (or `paste0`), you can benefit from its natural vectorization instead of using something like `apply` to go row-by-row. Try to take advantage of this natural vectorization as much as you can in R, doing otherwise is typically less efficiency and more code than necessary. Know that `paste` has two arguments that are relevant: `sep=` and `collapse=`. Looking at our use of it in my functions, you can think of `sep=` as combining across columns, and `collapse=` as combining across rows. Obviously, I did not want to combine across rows, but feel free to test `collapse=""` in that last function and see what happens. (Hint: one long string.)
- Not sure what to make of `dummy` ... created, never used.
- In general, when I used `group_by` I prefer to clean-up and `ungroup()` later, but this is under the assumption that I'll be using that frame again. In this case, the frame is disposable, so you do not technically need `ungroup`. I applaud the cleanliness (and habit-pattern) of using it, and its computation time is nearly 0, but know that it does not affect performance of `apply` or `paste`.